# Call Child component two times in parent component for two different scenario in Angular 14+

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is it possible to create common select Drop Down component so we can call as a selector in parent component with two different Array in Dropdown
Example: One field is Country and other is Sate and I want to create a common Drop Down to use in different parent component as per need.

Once I create a child component which have Drop Down in html and I want to use as Dynamic in parent component where on scenario is that we have two Fields in Parent component as a Drop Down and there i call the selector two times but while i change the value of first Drop Down the other one is also changes which is not required....
so i want two change both value without affect other Drop Down which is also used same child component as a Drop Down

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.